# Remove newlines javascript problem

Tags: javascript, newline

Hi i need to strip all spaces and newlines from a string in javascript... This is what i use and it doesn't work...

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 

<!-- 
var isShift=null; 
var isNN = (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape")!=-1); 
var OP = (navigator.appName.indexOf("Opera")!=-1); 
if(OP)isNN=true; 
var key; 
function shift(event){ 
key = (isNN) ? event.which : event.keyCode; 
if (key==16)isShift=1; 
} 
function process(event){ 
key = (isNN) ? event.which : event.keyCode; 
if(document.layers&&event.modifiers==4){ 
isShift=1; 
} 
if (key==13&&isShift!=1){ 
var chatmsg = $("#chatmsg");

var cmessage = chatmsg.val();

cmessage = cmessage.replace(/\s/g, ''); 

if(cmessage=="")
{
document.myForm.chatmsg.value = "";
return false;
}
else
{
sendMsg(); 
}
} 
if (key!=16)isShift=null; 
} 
//--> 

function sendMsg(){ 
var chatmsg = $("#chatmsg");

$.post("sendchat.php",{ chatmsg: chatmsg.val()} ,  
function(data)
{
$("#msgtousr").html(data).show();
$("#msgtousr").html(data).fadeOut(2000);
document.myForm.chatmsg.value = "";
});
}
</script>


<form name='myForm' method='POST' style='margin:0px'>
<textarea name='chatmsg' onkeypress='return process(event)' onkeydown='shift(event)' style='width:278px;height:70px;border:2px solid white;background-color:turquoise;color:blue' id='chatmsg'></textarea>
</form>
```

This is my chat if it has an error checking if the user typed something in in the javascript i suspect the replace function to misbehave

Comment: it sais that it couldn't find the value of replace

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to strip all spaces and newlines? Only one regex is necessary:

```
cmessage = cmessage.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try...

`cmessage = cmessage.replace(/\s/g, '');`

`\s` in this case stands for "all white space" which includes spaces and newline characters.

[Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)